Nginx Ingress Controller - Api responding in port 80 and 443
I need my API hosted in AKS to respond in ports 80 and 443. In port 80 because some of my current clients are using port 80 "hardcoded" and their HttpClients do not follow redirects...
my first try was:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myApp-service
  namespace: myAppe-main
  labels:
    app: myApp-service
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
    - port: 443
      targetPort: 443
      protocol: TCP
      name: https
  selector:
    app: myApp-deploy
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myApp-ingress
  namespace: myApp-main
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: H2C
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/secure-backends: 'true'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: 'true'
spec:
  rules:
    - host: myApp.MyInternalDns.net
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              service:
                name: myApp-service
                port:
                    number: 80
            path: /
            pathType: Prefix
      https:
        paths:
          - backend:
              service:
                name: myApp-service
                port:
                    number: 443
            path: /
            pathType: Prefix

Although AKS accepts this yaml, it chops off the https part of it...
How can I make the ingress open both ports and have it working on http and https?

To set up Nginx Ingress Controller in AKS that responds on both HTTP (port 80) and HTTPS (port 443), and routes traffic correctly to your services, you need to configure both the Ingress resource and the associated service. It looks like there might be a mistake or misconfiguration in your YAML, especially around the https rules under the Ingress specification, which is not a valid field directly under rules.
Ensure that the Nginx Ingress Controller is installed in your AKS cluster. If it's not already installed
helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
helm repo update
helm install nginx-ingress ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --namespace ingress-basic --create-namespace

Configure your deployment and service
Example (replace with your own deployment file) -
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginxdemos/hello
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myapp-service
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    app: myapp
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    name: http


Now set up Ingress to handle HTTP and HTTPS.
Configure Your Ingress Resource accordingly, i.e. you need to define TLS settings for HTTPS support. If your service needs to support HTTPS directly (not just terminating at the ingress), ensure your application inside the pod is configured for HTTPS and listening on port 443. In most cases, you'll terminate SSL at the ingress and forward traffic as HTTP to your pods.
Example-
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myapp-ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  ingressClassName: "nginx"
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - "myapp.example.com"
    secretName: myapp-tls
  rules:
  - host: "myapp.example.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: myapp-service
            port:
              number: 80


If you haven’t created a TLS secret yet and are using a self-signed certificate for testing then
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout myapp.key -out myapp.crt -subj "/CN=myapp.example.com/O=myapp"

kubectl create secret tls myapp-tls --key myapp.key --cert myapp.crt -n default


Done. You can verify as below
kubectl get ingress -n default


References:

Expose an AKS service over HTTP or HTTPS using Application Gateway

